# can't use galmorous package in react-native

Tags: react-native, glamorous

I tried to use glamorous package in react-native.
So I used command as following.

```
npm install --save glamorous-native
```

But I encountered error

```
npm ERR! path E:\Project\IOS\react-Native\Log_IN_DEMO\node_modules\glamorous-native
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'E:\Project\IOS\react-Native\Log_IN_DEMO\node_modules\glamorous-native' -> 'E:\Project\IOS\react-Native\Log_IN_DEMO\node_modules\.glamorous-native.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Autho\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-03T08_14_26_976Z-debug.log
```

This is Log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'galmorous-native' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.12.0
4 verbose npm-session 875ecedb0dc7d640
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/galmorous-native 4267ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for galmorous-native@latest 404 Not Found: galmorous-native@latest
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 5404ms
11 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: galmorous-native@latest
11 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
11 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
11 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
11 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
11 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
11 verbose stack     at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
12 verbose cwd E:\Project\IOS\react-Native\Log_IN_DEMO
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "galmorous-native"
15 verbose node v10.12.0
16 verbose npm  v6.4.1
17 error code E404
18 error 404 Not Found: galmorous-native@latest
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What is the reason?
Anyone know the reason?
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Error :-

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: galmorous-native@latest
```

I think you have spelled **glamorous-native** wrong.